# Why Do I always get Iran's ip?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, exit-relays

I'm using tor in Iran .
My question is why do i always get Iran exit nodes even after configure the torrc file to use strict exit nodes?

my torrc exitnodes config:

```
 ExitNodes {nl} StrictNodes 1
```

Note: Tor browser works just fine as a Anti-censorship tool and I don't have any problem with surfing the web but i'm worried that it would be a security issue.